# Benefits of Post-Redirect-Get

Tags: zend-framework2

When I started with ZF2 the first module I used was ZfcUser. When I debug it's controller's code I found a weird way (at least for me) to manage actions. I found code like

```
    $prg = $this->prg('zfcuser/changepassword');

    if ($prg instanceof Response) {
        return $prg;
    } elseif ($prg === false) {
        return array(
            'status' => $status,
            'changePasswordForm' => $form,
        );
    }

    //VALIDATE FORM AND DATABASE STUFF
    (...)
```

The behaviour is as follows:

1. The first load $prg is false, so it returns the form.
2. When you submit the page, $prg is an instance of Response, so it returns $prg.
3. When $prg is returned, the same function is called again and $prg becomes an array with all the posted data, so it jumps to the validation of form and database stuff.

I thought it was a weird approach so I override all the needed functions replacing this with the simple request->isPost(). I found it easier to handle the first load/data posted.

I didn't give it more importance until now. I'm facing the Post-Redirect-Get approach again when I'm trying to upload files: it seems that is needed to prevent user to re-select the file and re-upload when a validation error rises on a form.

What's the point of the Post-Redirect-Get? When do you recommend the use of it (apart of the commented file upload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> When a user sends a POST request (e.g. after submitting a form), their browser will try to protect them from sending the POST again, breaking the back button, causing browser warnings and pop-ups, and sometimes reposting the form. Instead, when receiving a POST, we should store the data in a session container and redirect the user to a GET request.

So the purpose of this plugin is to improve user experience. You must have came across this problem when you submit a form and try to refresh the page you get a pop-up message like (example from google chrome):

> Confirm Form Resubmission: The page that you're looking for used information that  you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?

You can get more details in the docs for [Post/Redirect/Get Plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#post-redirect-get-plugin), or [File Post/Redirect/Get Plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin) if your form handles files uploads.

**NOTE: For the *File Post/Redirect/Get Plugin - Example Usage* there's a typo on line 16, you should use `$this->filePrg()` instead of `$this->prg()`. It should be like the line below.**

```
$prg = $this->filePrg($myForm, '/user/profile-pic', true);
```